# Installing pip for python 3.6.2 on MAC OS 10.12.6

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

Python 3 installed from python.org on Mac OS 10.12.6
I used `sudo easy_install pip` to install pip
It spit out a bunch of errors and then went ahead and installed pip in the
2.7 directories.
What can I do to get the correct version of pip installed in the 3.6 directories.

Thanks in advance.

```
roberts-MacBook-Pro:~ robertknourek$ sudo easy_install pip
Password:
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Best match: pip 9.0.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/11/b6/abcb525026a4be042b486df43905d6893fb04f05aac21c32c638e939e447/pip-9.0.1.tar.gz#md5=35f01da33009719497f01a4ba69d63c9
Processing pip-9.0.1.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-IhUWLC/pip-9.0.1/setup.cfg
Running pip-9.0.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-IhUWLC/pip-9.0.1/egg-dist-tmp-iyGXIy
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
```

Comment: Pip comes with Python 3.6...

Comment: 1) What you need is `pip3`, not just `pip`; 2) `pip3` is already there, no need to install it.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, pip3 was already there.